# Scheme: define-syntax-rule pattern matching syntax

Tags: scheme, syntax-error, racket

I would like to rewrite this:

```
(define-syntax match-rewriter
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (patt body) ...)
      (λ (x) (match x (patt body) ... (_ x))))))
```

using (define-syntax-rule pattern template) but I can't seem to get the syntax right.  Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(define-syntax-rule (match-rewriter (patt body) ...)
  (lambda (x) (match x (patt body) ... (_ x))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's almost exactly what I was using but I see now that I had an extra pair of parentheses throwing off the pattern.